# Can a function $f$ be differentiable at $a$ but $f(a)$ doesn't exist or $ f(a) \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Can a function $f$ be differentiable at $x=a$ , but $f(a)$ doesn't exist or $f(a) \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$

Because a friend told me:
A function is differentiable at $x=a$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+} \frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a-} \frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} = l \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, it can't be. Because $f$ is differentiable, it's also continuous, and because differentiability is equivalent to the existence of the derivative, which is a limit, the point $a$ is a limit point. Because all of that the limit exists and is equals to $f(a)$.

Comment: $f(a)$ has to exist to calculate $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: What if it exists but $f(a) ≠ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$

Comment: It can't. Differentiability implies continuity.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(a)$ exists, then $f$ is continuous at $a$; that is, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$ must hold. $f$ must be defined at $a$ for the limit $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ to even make sense. And to show that $f$ is continuous at $a$, we have that if that limit exists and equals $L$, then
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to a}\Bigl( f(x)-f(a)+f(a)\Bigr)\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left( (f(x)-f(a))\left(\frac{x-a}{x-a}\right)+f(a)\right)\tag{1}\\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\left(\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)(x-a) + f(a)\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)\right) + \left(\lim_{x\to a}f(a)\right)\tag{3}\\
&= (L)(0)+f(a)\tag{4}\\
&= f(a).
\end{align*}$$
Int he calculations above: (1) is valid, because the two functions are equal everywhere near $a$, even though one is not defined at $a$. Step (3) is valid because each of the limits in question exists, with the only possibly difficult one being the first, which we are **assuming** exists. And step (4) is just evaluating those limits.

Thus, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$, showing $f$ is continuous at $a$.